# Changes to simple_query_string query behavior in Elasticsearch 6

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-6

After upgrading from Elasticsearch 5.6.8 to 6.2.4, I am noticing a change to the behavior of simple_query_string that I can't seem to find documented in the breaking changes. If you run the following against both versions, you will see that "Test *" would match "Test Value" in 5, but no longer matches in version 6. Did I miss something in the upgrade notes, and is there a way to replicate the 5.X behavior in 6.X?

```
PUT test_query
{
  "mappings": {
    "test_type": {
      "properties": {
          "my_field": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "standard"
          }
        }
    }
  }
}

POST /test_query/test_type
{
  "my_field": "Test Value Here"
}

GET test_query/_search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "my_field"
      ],
      "query": "Test *",
      "default_operator": "and"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear examples -- I was able to recreate the issue very quickly! I'm throwing in the towel, though. :) I see one likely culprit, though. When I run the search against the `_analyze` API I can see that the word "test" matches the document under both 5.x and 6.x. But in 5.x the resulting score is *added* to 0 while in 6.x the score is *multiplied* by zero.  There is a breaking change to the query normalization logic ( https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/breaking_60_search_changes.html#_query_normalization ) that might explain that change in behavior.

Comment: This was filed here as well: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/31150

Comment: Thank you for looking into this @JasonRosendale. The github question did end up referencing the fix for this in the next minor version  https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/28871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug and will be fixed in a future release https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/28871.